# Use manage_pages permission to develop an Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Right now I create a webpage where user can login to it with their Facebook credentials. I want to be able that this website is able to post to the wall of the Facebook Pages which the user own or maintains.

I found a nice "tutorial" for that procedure [here](http://www.yorkstreetlabs.com/blog/Publish-to-Your-Facebook-Pages-Wall-with-PHP). In order to get an insight which pages the user maintains or owns I have to have the permission called "manage_pages", but this permission is blocked by Facebook because of the following failure:

[image: Blocked Facebook permission]

I get what I have to do in order to "unlock" this permission, but right now I'm not able to submit the App for an review, because I'm at the beginning of the development of it, and I'm pretty sure it will be declined from Facebook at the moment.

So is there a way to get access to these test-permission or test-users etc. in order to develop the app correctly?

Comment: You can always use the admin user of the app for that

Comment: What do you mean? I'm the admin user, and I want to test it with my Facebook Account. But then the above message appears...

Comment: Without the message above or with it?

Comment: With the message, but I can get the permission if I use the admin user. Just tried it in Graph Explorer

Comment: Check `/me/accounts` afterwards to see if it worked

Comment: ok i checked it. after the message above there is another message that my facebook app wants to get the permission to manage my pages. so i guess this works! thanks. do you know if i'm able to post on the wall of the page even if it is not public now (it is at the moment not accessible for other people) -> just to test it correctly (my post-to-page code)? (i'm asking that because it doesn't work now)